# What is the 0x43 MIDI event?

Tags: midi

I'm trying to write a MIDI parser, but I'm reaching a MIDI event that isn't documented in the official documentation (namely http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php).

In one of the MIDI files that I have, I notice that immediately after a note-on event of `81 70 90 3c 00`, I get the following bytes: `00 43 1e`.  However, I have not seen any documentation about `0x43` acting as a MIDI event identifier.  How should I interpret `0x43`, and where can I find more information about that?

Edit: The MIDI is interpretable, because I've loaded it up into Logic Pro without issues.  Additionally, my interpretation up to the `0x43` has been accurate.

Comment: The way that MIDIs work is that they have at least one delta time byte in order to tell the interpreter how much time it should wait after the previous event before acting on the MIDI event (read more at http://www.ccarh.org/courses/253/handout/vlv/).  In this case, `81 70` is the delta time, and the actual event identifier starts with the byte `0x90`, which is note-on, and is then followed by the byte `0x3c`, which tells me to turn on the note C4, and finally `0x00`, which is volume zero (these two bytes are equivalent to note-off).

Comment: This also matches up with the expected notes in the MIDI.

Comment: UPDATE: I made the supposition that this non-standard MIDI event is actually just an implicit note-on command for the note, which in this case is `0x43` AKA G4, at volume `0x1e`.  I've altered my code to accommodate this and now it seems to parse correctly, so I assume that this is the actual case.  What's interesting to me now is how does this interaction work with notes with bits that are complementary to standard MIDI event identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
81 70 90 3c 00 00 43 1e
```

`81 70`: delta time (240 ticks)
`90 3c 00`: Note-On message (actually note off)
`00`: delta time
`43 1e`: Note-On message, using running status.

The MIDI Specification says:

> RUNNING STATUS
>
> For Voice and Mode messages only. When a Status byte is received and processed, the receiver will remain in that status until a different Status byte is received. Therefore, if the same Status byte would be repeated, it can optionally be omitted so that only the Data bytes need to be sent. Thus, with Running Status, a complete message can consist of only Data bytes.
>
> Running Status is especially helpful when sending long strings of Note On/Off messages, where "Note On with Velocity of 0" is used for Note Off.

Status bytes always have the most significant bit set (80–FF), while Data bytes always have it clear (00–7F). Therefore, it is always possible to distinguish between them.

Comment: Fantastic.  I thought that it would be as such, but I hadn't found any documentation to back up that intuition.  Much appreciated!